# Join two SQL tables based on an alias incremental value

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join

I have one table called @myTable that's returning an cycling incremental value called am_id. I am storing some variables with IDs in another table called @myTableVariable.

```
DECLARE @myTable TABLE (id INT, name varchar(20))
insert into @myTable values(1,'one  '),(2,'two  '),(3,'three'),(4,'four'),(5,'five'),(6,'six'),(7,'seven'),(8,'eight'),(9,'nine'),(10,'ten'),(11,'eleven'),(12,'twelve'),(13,'thirteen')

DECLARE @myTableVariable TABLE (id INT, name varchar(20))
insert into @myTableVariable values(1,'Roberto'),(2,'Gail'),(3,'Dylan'),(4,'Ben')
select * from @myTableVariable

declare @start decimal(10)=1;
declare @end decimal(10)=4;
declare @increment decimal(10)=1;

SELECT f.name, (@start + @increment * (row_number() over (order by id) - 1) % cast(1 + round((@end - @start) / @increment, 0) as int)) AS am_id
FROM @myTable AS f
```

I would like to JOIN the two tables on @myTable.am_id = @myTableVariable.id, however it's not possible to JOIN using an alias...

```
SELECT f.name, (@start + @increment * (row_number() over (order by id) - 1) % cast(1 + round((@end - @start) / @increment, 0) as int)) AS am_id
FROM @myTable AS f
LEFT JOIN @myTableVariable AS v ON v.vid = am_id
```

Any ideas how I can join these tables?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery and then join

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT name, (@start + @increment * (row_number() over (order by id) - 1) % cast(1 + round((@end - @start) / @increment, 0) as int)) AS am_id
FROM @myTable) AS f
LEFT JOIN @myTableVariable AS v ON v.id = f.am_id
```